# I'm looking for some sort of tree (category) mechanism, or hints to implement own

Tags: python, tree, categories

I'm looking for some sort of 'tree category' mechanism.
I can describe it like this.
Let's have a schema (which can be extended with items, like add garlic to vegatables)

- things

  - vegetables

    - carrots
    - cucamber
    - others
  - fruits

    - apples
    - bannanas
    - others
- others

Main functions of this should be:

- extending like the above garlic example
- easy access to childrens (subcategories), like for *fruits* get *apples*, *bannanas* and so on.. .
- nice visualization, not worse then this freaky fancy site:
  http://whatdoyousuggest.net/#|default|default (by js raphealas plugin if my reasearch is correct)

I'd be a part of python based web service (django, flask , pyramid) so doing this with python is desired or other landuage with easy ingration.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: Python has dictionaries which can be nested (a key in an outer dictionary can be associated with an inner dictionary, etc. which is what you tree structure resembles. Dictionaries haave a number of methods for manipulating their contents which could be utilized to accomplish the operations you seek. The only missing feature might be that they are unordered, but there are workarounds for that. So unless you have specific programming question, I too, think you question is to0 vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to trees , you could look through basic principals, including Nested Sets:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model
Ready source code on Nested Sets for python/django:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-treebeard

Comment: This is what I wanted, especially django-treebeard, thx.
Sorry that I messed with stackoverflow faq, i've read it and now i know what kind of questions are welcome here.